# Is it possible to convert text that's in json format to a string without giving errors? (C#)

Tags: c#, json, string, quotes

In my C# program, I'd like to create a string that's written in json format, so it contains a bunch of quotations, too many for me to manually go through and fix.

So is there any way to fix all " in a string and stop them from giving errors easily?

`string shopJson = "{ "refreshIntervalHrs": 1, "dailyPurchaseHrs": 24, "expiration": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z", "storefronts": [ { "name": "BRStandaloneStorefront", "catalogEntries": [] }`

Comment: Show code and the json, we cant debug a story

Comment: find and replace, maybe with a regex expression

Comment: I edited the post to show what you want @00110001

Comment: So, you don't usually write the json your self, you usually serialize it from a class / record / struct / anonymous type. that way you don't have to worry about quotes and other pesky issues

Comment: **[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)** is not a format - it is not just a fancy string.  It is serialized data.

Comment: If you really have to manually do it there are different ways to go about it and I usually opt in for string interpolation ```string s = $"{"hello"} {"world"}"```

Comment: I think you need to serialize the data.. using few libraries

Comment: `JSON is not a format` And the link then states `is an open standard file format, and data interchange format,` ;)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fix all quotes and stop errors"? What "fix" do you mean, what "errors" are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

So the best practice would be to use a library like newtonjsoft and create a class and then serialize in to that class. an example is like this :

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
  //{
  //  "Name": "Apple",
 //  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
 //  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

if you have the json string you expect you can use a helper tool online to convert here: https://quicktype.io/csharp/

Or

in visual studio you can create a class using the special paste feature in a class file its a process so here is a link on how to do that as well:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/

you json should be :

```
 { "refreshIntervalHrs": 1, "dailyPurchaseHrs": 24, "expiration": "9999-12- 
   31T23:59:59.999Z", "storefronts": [ { "name": "BRStandaloneStorefront", 
   "catalogEntries": [] }]}
```

and the class would be like:

```
 public class SomeClassName
{
    [JsonProperty("refreshIntervalHrs")]
    public long RefreshIntervalHrs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dailyPurchaseHrs")]
    public long DailyPurchaseHrs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expiration")]
    public DateTimeOffset Expiration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("storefronts")]
    public Storefront[] Storefronts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Storefront
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("catalogEntries")]
    public object[] CatalogEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can instruct the Newtonsoft serializer to use [camelCasing](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) so you don't need to add an attribute to every property